# Atom IDE Terminal showing Blank in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: command-line, ide, atom

The Terminal package in Atom is blank with a blinking cursor. can't enter commands.

Installed Terminal package with this command - returned successful in terminal

```
apm install platformio-ide-terminal
```

have hunted online and can't seem to find many solutions related to Atom IDE on Linux/Ubuntu

have attempted as super user but it returns error as atom missing modules.

```
jekyllz@Jeky:~$ sudo apm install platformio-ide-terminal
[sudo] password for jekyllz: 
Installing platformio-ide-terminal to /root/.atom/packages ^[x✗

> node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch@0.9.0-beta21.legacy install /tmp/apm-install-dir-2020830-13934-1f3f7tb.uc5s/node_modules/platformio-ide-terminal/node_modules/node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch
> prebuild-install || node scripts/install.js


sh: 1: prebuild-install: Permission denied
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/tmp/apm-install-dir-2020830-13934-1f3f7tb.uc5s/node_modules/platformio-ide-terminal/node_modules/node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch/scripts/install.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/apm-install-dir-2020830-13934-1f3f7tb.uc5s/package.json'
npm WARN apm-install-dir-2020830-13934-1f3f7tb.uc5s No description
npm WARN apm-install-dir-2020830-13934-1f3f7tb.uc5s No repository field.
npm WARN apm-install-dir-2020830-13934-1f3f7tb.uc5s No README data
npm WARN apm-install-dir-2020830-13934-1f3f7tb.uc5s No license field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch@0.9.0-beta21.legacy install: `prebuild-install || node scripts/install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-pty-prebuilt-multiarch@0.9.0-beta21.legacy install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.atom/.apm/_logs/2020-09-30T09_37_26_282Z-debug.log
```

Thank you very much for reading/helping!